# Get notified on stock unavailability

Tags: php, ajax, magento, stock, magento-1.8

I am trying to create a "Notify me" feature if the stock is unavailable.

On search on admin panel, I could find only that a user should `sign up / log in` to get notified about the stock availability.

But I just want to let the user (*a guest*) enter only his/her email address to get notified.

How should I do this?

Please give suggestions..

**EDIT**:

I have got this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11735592/1577396), which gives me a way to start.

Till now what I did is added the following code in my template file which is creating a url for redirect (*thinking to do it in ajax way, to stop page refreshing*).

```
<?php
      $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; 
      $base64 = strtr(base64_encode($actual_link), '+/=', '-_,'); 
      $postUrl = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/efk/productalert/add/stock/product_id/" . $simpleProduct->getId() . "/uenc/". $base64; 
?>
```

In the above code, `efk` is my project folder name.

After this, I have gone to `productalert/add/stock` controller method i.e `stockAction()` which is calling `sign up / login` form (*I think so*) using `$model->save();`.

How should I disable this save calling and add my own small overlay which holds a textbox to enter a email address?

Comment: `$base64 = strtr(base64_encode($actual_link), '+/=', '-_,'); ` Oh wow why?

Comment: @Brad I saw this way in some post here on SO.. btw I am new to php.. I think this is not needed may be magento provides the same as built-in method.. I couldn't find it.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do some really hackish form of URL encoding... Unless you have to do that to be compatible with something (I'm not familiar with Magento), use `urlencode()`.

Comment: Just a note: If you haven't considered it already, do make sure that you verify notification requests via email (similar to verifying account signups by clicking a link). Otherwise, your service could get abused and your mail may be identified as spam.

Answer (score 4):

Magento has "Notify me when product is back in stock" feature out of the box. It can be configured in admin panel: system / configuration / catalog / product alerts and product alerts run settings.

You're right, it works only for registred customers. To make it working for guest users some coding is required. I'd say you need to do the following steps:

1. Add `email` column to `product_alert_stock` table
2. Create new controller and action (believe me, it's better than you override existing one via config.xml) which extends `Mage_ProductAlert_AddController::stockAction()`. Your method will have to set guest's email to `productalert/stock` model.
3. Create subscription form and make sure it submits data to your new controller/action.
4. Update (override) `Mage_ProductAlert_Model_Observer::_processStock()` method to make it respect situations when "customer" has no ID but has email.

When you'll be testing, I suggest you to install [SMTP Pro Email extension](https://github.com/aschroder/Magento-SMTP-Pro-Email-Extension) and [mailcatcher](https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher) to ease the testing process.

Answer (score 2):

We have done this (http://www.alfresia.co.uk/sorrento-side-table.html/). Here we ended up creating a custom module as when we did this magento did not support any product alert system for the guest users (i do not know if this is supported now).

We first created a text box which would appear on product page where the product is out of stock. We were saving this info in one of our custom tables where we the schema was {id, email, product_sku, status} (status had three values Awaiting Stock, In Stock, and Already Notified).

We then wrote an observer which was hooked to `cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after` event, this helped us get the product sku which has been back in stock, and update all entries in our custom table with status In Stock and send a mail to the user.

This is how we did it, surely there will be a much cleaner way doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You could have work with plugins. MagentoCommerce has loads of plugins/extensions which does the same

Free Version - http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-out-of-stock-subscription-1350.html

Comment: Doesn't support for `1.8`.. :(

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/out-of-stock-notification-7896.html .. could you check this .. it supports 1.7 should work with 1.8 as well

Answer (score 0):

I too had similar requirement, and have installed 'http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-out-of-stock-subscription-1350.html' this plugin. 
Well this plugin does the job, But they have override complete product view page template  instead of simply adding a new block. By this your custom development on product view page development might get reflected on frontend.

Or else this plugin  definitely does the job.

Comment: I installed this extension. this works if the complete configurable product is set as "out of stock" only. please help. please go through the comments in below post where I explained clearly about my issue..

Comment: Check modules view.phtml files once. And see if you can figure out the bug.

Answer (score 0):

This http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-out-of-stock-subscription-1350.html plugin is really good but it breaks for configurable product types and it completely overrides the product controller which makes your system vulnerable to future upgrades. I think observers should be hooked to events where the product is back in stock and should update the users.

Comment: I installed this extension. this works if the complete configurable product is set as "out of stock" only.

Comment: so when the configurable product is in stock, does it render from the default magento controller??

Comment: yes... If I manually set in admin config that the configurable product is out of stock then only I can see the out of stock notification. This is completely different from what I want actually. What I want is I have three simple products in each configurable product. and if any of the simple product has quantity as `0` then the out of stock notification should be visible automatically. Can you please install this extension and try to synchonize with what I am trying to explain here? that would be really helpful for me. thanks.. :)

Comment: I misunderstood your first comment, now I get your point. I think in that case you will have to write some code, in order to get this working or just rewrite the plugin to make sure it works for you. I reckon just write observer methods they are easy implementation, it might be just neater than rewrting an extension and then debugging. Also I am travelling over the weekend and does not seem to be possible for me to install it. Sorry !!!